# How to Add data in list or map with (key and value) flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
[![app for multiple choice question][1]][1]
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oNk5.jpg):  [image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/O14Ez.jpg

Above example, I have multiple questions, I want to add a list with **question id: option** when anyone selects on the app. like a question 1 and user select option (1,2,3,4) like select 2 
then in list or map add `qid 1: with option 2 selected` please help me. I don't know how to add question id and selected option in list or map.

```
  List<Map<String, String>>  options=[] ;


        setState(() {
                          question = Quiz[index].id;
                          options.remove(Quiz[index].t_op2);
                          options.remove(Quiz[index].t_op3);
                          options.remove(Quiz[index].t_op4);
                          options.contains(Quiz[index].t_op1)?options.remove(Quiz[index].t_op1):options.add(Quiz[index].id,Quiz[index].t_op1);

                        });
```

json data received 
   [image]

Comment: Can you share you json which contain question and option? So i will make list base on your requirement

Comment: question updated, please check

Comment: why dont you just create a model class and serialize the json to this object, i think it will be more efficient than adding and removing string maps.

Answer (score 0):

```
questionOption[i].isSelected = true;
```